# How to nest a Tk instance inside another in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Tkinter app, and I need to nest a Tk object inside another. Is there any way to do it?
This is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def new():
   r =Tk()
   Label(r, text="new window").pack()
Message(root, text="Lorem ipsum dolorsunt in culpa qui officia orum.", width=50).pack()
Button(root, text="new window", command=new, padx=30).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045401/why-are-multiple-instances-of-tk-discouraged)

Comment: It looks like you did little to no research. There are countless post on how to get a 2nd window in Tkinter. `Toplevel()` is the method you are looking for. That said your question is not formatted properly.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: they don't just want a second window, I think they want a second window _inside_ a window.

Comment: @BryanOakley so just a frame? Or something they can drag around?

Comment: @Mike-SMT: I'm assuming they want to drag it around.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want. You cannot embed an instance of `Tk` inside another instance of `Tk`.